# SharedPreferences duplicate saved data

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

if I have ID = 5 and I want to save in `SharedPreferences`  I got result 5,5 which is wrong the code I use is

```
String FavoritsKey = "com.test";
SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("SpeakEgyptPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
preferences.edit().putString(FavoritsKey,  preferences.getString(FavoritsKey, "")+","+ selected.Id).apply();
```

For Example

the first time I want to save 5 => supposed to get string =",5" but I get ",5,5" an so on

How to solve the repeat

Comment: That code is working as one would expect. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Your question is unclear, what the expected output ?

Comment: `preferences.getString(FavoritsKey, "")+","+ selected.Id` says: `append to the previously saved value: "," followed by the current id` - so, the next value (assuming that id = 5) would be: **5,5,5**. and the next one: **5,5,5,5**. And so on

Comment: @FrankN.Stein how to solve that

Comment: change your code with this String FavoritsKey = "com.test";
SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("SpeakEgyptPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
preferences.edit().putString(FavoritsKey,  preferences.getString(FavoritsKey, "")+","+ selected.Id).commit();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've interpreted your question as follows: You want to save the ID(`"5"`) to sharedpreferences, and when you retrieve it, it should be returned as `",5"`. Which means you can either save `"5"` in your sharedprefs and add the `,` on retrieval, or save the id including the comma (`",5"`).

```
/* Storing the id */
String FavoritsKey = "com.test";
String valueToSave = "" + selected.ID; // we'll store "5" in sharedPreferences
Editor edit = preferences.edit();    
edit.putString(FavoritsKey, valueToSave);
edit.commit(); //almost the same as apply, you can read the API docs if you want

/* Retrieving the id and prefix it */
String valueToRetrieve = preferences.getString(FavoritsKey, ""); // retrieve "5"
valueToRetrieve = "," + valueToRetrieve; // well prefix the "5" with "," for ",5"
```

Or the other way around

```
/* Storing the id with prefixed comma*/
String FavoritsKey = "com.test";
String valueToSave = "," + selected.ID; // we'll store ",5" in sharedPreferences
Editor edit = preferences.edit();    
edit.putString(FavoritsKey, valueToSave);
edit.commit(); //almost the same as apply, you can read the API docs if you want

/* Retrieving the id with a prefixed comma */
String valueToRetrieve = preferences.getString(FavoritsKey, ""); // retrieve ",5"
```

Your code, however, did exactly as it should.

```
preferences.edit().putString(FavoritsKey,  preferences.getString(FavoritsKey, "")+","+ selected.Id).apply();
```

Lets look closer. In sharedPreferences, on key `FavoritsKey`, you store:

```
preferences.getString(FavoritsKey, "")+","+ selected.Id) 
//lets assume ",5" was stored initially
//outcome is ",5" + "," + 5 => thats ",5,5"
//and the next time another ",5" is added, and so on, etc...
```